# Export excel React tengo que pulsar dos veces

Tags: reactjs

Uso la librería `react-data-export` y quiero hacer una descarga de un excel, el problema está en que debo pulsar dos veces en el botón.

Mi código:

```
import ReactExport from "react-data-export";
const ExcelFile = ReactExport.ExcelFile;
const ExcelSheet = ReactExport.ExcelFile.ExcelSheet;

class Principal extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            multiDataSet: []
        }
        this.getDatosExcel = this.getDatosExcel.bind(this);
    }

getDatosExcel() {
    let self = this;
    axios.get('/app/webapi/datos/excel'
        ).then(function (response) {
            self.setState({ multiDataSet: response.data});
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        });
}   
render() {
    return (
        <ExcelFile name="excel2" filename="excelDatos" element={<Button label="Exportar" icon="fa fa-file-excel-o" onClick={this.getDatosExcel}/>}>
            <ExcelSheet dataSet={this.state.multiDataSet} name="Datos_Excel"/>
        </ExcelFile>

    );
)
```

¿Cómo puedo hacer que espere a que la consulta finalice para descargar el excel?

Comment: utiliza la libreria yarn add react-export-excel, muy facil de integrarlar..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Debes cargar los datos en el dataset antes de utilizar el botón para descargarlos:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactExport from 'react-data-export';
const ExcelFile = ReactExport.ExcelFile;
const ExcelSheet = ReactExport.ExcelFile.ExcelSheet;

class Principal extends React.Component {
  state = {
    multiDataSet: [],
    isFetching: null
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getDatosExcel();
  }

  getDatosExcel = async () => {
    this.setState({ isFetching: true });
    try {
      const response = await axios.get('/app/webapi/datos/excel');
      this.setState({ multiDataSet: response.data, isFetching: false });
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
      this.setState({ isFetching: false });
    }
  };

  render() {
    const { isFetching, multiDataSet } = this.state;
    return (
      <ExcelFile
        name="excel2"
        filename="excelDatos"
        element={<Button label="Exportar" icon="fa fa-file-excel-o" disabled={isFetching || isFetching === null} />}
      >
        <ExcelSheet dataSet={multiDataSet} name="Datos_Excel" />
      </ExcelFile>
    );
  }
}

export default Principal;
```

**Edito**: tras el comentario de la necesidad de recargar datos cada vez que se hace click en un botón, propongo la siguiente solución:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactExport from 'react-data-export';
const ExcelFile = ReactExport.ExcelFile;
const ExcelSheet = ReactExport.ExcelFile.ExcelSheet;

class Download extends React.Component {
  state = {
    multiDataSet: [],
    isFetching: null,
    isLoaded: false,
  };

  getDatosExcel = async () => {
    this.setState({ isFetching: true });
    try {
      const response = await axios.get('/app/webapi/datos/excel');
      this.setState({
        multiDataSet: response.data,
        isFetching: false,
        isLoaded: true,
      });
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
      this.setState({ isFetching: false });
    }
  };

  render() {
    const { isFetching, multiDataSet, isLoaded } = this.state;
    return (
      <>
        <Button
          label="Exportar"
          icon="fa fa-file-excel-o"
          disabled={isFetching}
          onClick={this.getDatosExcel}
        >
          Cargar datos
        </Button>
        {isLoaded ? (
          <ExcelFile name="excel2" filename="excelDatos">
            <ExcelSheet dataSet={multiDataSet} name="Datos_Excel" />
          </ExcelFile>
        ) : null}
      </>
    );
  }
}

export default Download;
```

Con esto, tendrás que pulsar el botón de recargar datos y luego darle a download para descargar el archivo.

Comment: Hola, el problema es que debo consultar cada vez que pulsen el botón, y evitar que descargue el excel hasta que finalice la consulta, gracias.

Comment: Vale, edito la respuesta. Intenta, la próxima vez, dedicar un poco más de tiempo a la descripción del problema, porque si eso es lo que necesitas, no está explicado en la pregunta ;)